# JQuery Ignoring styling / position when appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I have written a simple Greasemonkey script to check the content of a path on site and, depending on the result, hopefully display a button floating in the bottom right.

Testing the following HTML, I managed to add the button but, when I wrap this in JQuery, it doesnt seem to have any styling effect:

```
(function() { 
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    $.get('/tap_active?u='+pathname, function(result){       
        if (/1/i.test (result) ) {
            alert ("Found it!");  
            $("body").append ( '<div id="gmSomeID"> <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a></div>' );
        }
    });  

    GM_addStyle(
        "#gmSomeID {"+
            "position: absolute;"+
            "bottom:0;"+
            "right:0;"+
        "}" 
    );
})();
```

The GM_addStyle here doesn't seem to have any affect as my append ends up right at the bottom of the body and not floating in the bottom right corner as hoped.

How does one override the styling of a appended item?

Comment: What is `GM_addStyle `? please share what that code does aswell, because right now its just a function calling with a string as an variable.

Comment: I believe GM_addStyle is a greasemonkey function (where this is written for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the $(..).css() method instead? Should be

```
$("#gmSomeID").css({"position" : "absolute", "bottom":"0",  "right":"0"})
```

Comment: Unfortunately this dosen't seem to take any effect as the text stays on the bottom left. Is there any way the CSS on the pace could be overriding this? Or, is declaration order important?

Comment: This is an inline style which means that it has the highest priority ( except if you have any "important" in your CSS classes. Also, be sure that you set the styles after the "gmSomeID" element exists on the DOM, else this will have no effect

Comment: I have updated my code to set this inplace of GM_addStyle above but this continues not to have an affect unfortunately.

Comment: As I can see, you're issuing a GET request. This is an async function and you cant be sure that the function will be completed by the tyme the GM_addStyle is called. Simply move the GM_AddStyle after $("body").append ( '<div id="gm> ...... ) and try again.

Comment: $.get('/tap_active?u='+pathname, function(result){       
        if (/1/i.test (result) ) {
            alert ("Found it!");  
            $("body").append ( '<div id="gmSomeID"> <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a></div>' );

GM_addStyle(
        "#gmSomeID {"+
            "position: absolute;"+
            "bottom:0;"+
            "right:0;"+
        "}" 
    );
        }
    });

Comment: Should be like this

Comment: Thats it exactly! Thanks :)